# Drop multiple tables in a table using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I use PDW and I have query which creates a list of tables to be dropped.

*Table Q :*

```
TableName
---------
   a
   b
   c
   d
   e
```

`a,b,c,d,e` are the list of tables in the database which should be dropped.

I want to write a dynamic sql query which will drop the tables `a` to `e` listed in table `Q` without any human intervention.

Is it possible?

Comment: So the list of tables to drop is in another table? Something sounds like the design got derailed somewhere. And not really sure what you mean about no human intervention. At some level there has to be human intervention.

Comment: The path to your solution starts here. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following dynamic sql to achieve this: *(assuming that the table name is `Table Q` and the column name is `TABLE_NAME`)*

```
DECLARE @strQuery as varchar(MAX)

SET @strQuery = ''

SELECT @strQuery = @strQuery + 'DROP TABLE [' + TABLE_NAME + '];' FROM [Table Q] 

EXEC(strQuery)
```

Comment: Improvement: Let this is a job so there is no human intervention